# the subdifferential at points of differentiability in infinite dimensional space

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $ f: X\to (-\infty,+\infty]$ that $ X$ is **an infinite dimensional space**.

What are the conditions for $f$ and space $X$ to have the following equality correct?

$$\partial f(x)=\{\nabla f(x)\}$$ for all $x\in X$

I know when space X is **finite dimensional** and $f$ is proper convex function then
$$\partial f(x)=\{\nabla f(x)\}$$ for all $x\in X$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by $\nabla f$. If $X$ is a normed vector space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is Gâteaux differentiable, then $\partial f(x) = \{DF(x)\}$ for the Gâteaux derivative $DF(x)\in X^*$ of $F$ at $x$; the proof is virtually identical to the finite-dimensional one using the definition of the Gâteaux derivative and the characterization of the convex subdifferential using the directional derivative (shameless plug: Theorem 4.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04180).

If $\nabla F(x)\in X$ is the gradient, then this of course requires $X$ to be a Hilbert space.

Comment: Christian Clason $\nabla f(x)$ is the gradient. Is the proof similar in this case?

Comment: The proof is the same, you just need to use the Riesz representation theorem to identify $DF(x)\in X^*$ with $\nabla F(x)\in X$; this is standard and not at all specific to convex analysis.

Comment: Thanks. I saw (shameless plug: Theorem 4.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04180). it is very useful.
Can you introduce another useful resource in the field of optimization?

Comment: Well, that depends on what specifically you're interested in. If it's first-order algorithms, there's an expanded version https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.00216 (due for an update soon). The Preface there has a good number of references to textbooks and monographs in this area. I think the books by Schirotzek and Bauschke/Combettes in particular are very good.

Comment: It's great. Thanks